# Convert numpy ndarray to non-numpy datatype

Tags: numpy, pandas, networkx

I'm trying to convert an element of an `np.ndarray` to a native integer type.

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 2.5])
>>> type(x[0])
<type 'numpy.float64'>
>>> type(x.astype(int)[0])
<type 'numpy.int64'>
```

What I'd like is:

```
>>> type(x.astype('something here')[0])
<type 'int'>
```

---

*This is the original question, asked in a `pandas` context, but it turns out to boil down to a problem with `np.ndarray.astype()`*

`astype(int)` maintains the numpy-ness of the integers in a `Series`:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([1,2,3])
>>> type(s[0])
<type 'numpy.int64'>
>>> type(s[0].astype(int))
<type 'numpy.int64'>
```

Is there anyway to cast a series, or even just one element of a series as a native datatype such that the following could be achieved?

```
>>> type(s[0].dosomething())
<type 'int'>
```

#### Why am I asking this?

I'm trying to export a `pandas.DataFrame` to GEXF format using `networkx.write_gexf()`.

The exporter insists that all data used respond to `type(x)` with either `int`, `float`, `bool` or a few others. It doesn't know what to do with a `numpy.int64`.

Comment: Why don't you convert your DataFrame into a NetworkX object first, using `g = nx.from_numpy_matrix(df.values)`, assuming `df` is your DataFrame? Then it's just `nx.write_gexf(g, path)`?

Comment: (Hi Rob, it's Stephan)

Comment: I'm trying to add attributes to my edges. `nx.set_edge_attributes(G, 'myattr', df['attribute'].astype(int).to_dict())` works fine but then `nx.write_gexf()` complains.

Comment: Hmm. I've never added attributes after the fact, only built it from a df in one go, then relabeled it.

Comment: Does `s2 = pd.Series(s, dtype=object)` work?  It does for me, but I'm reluctant to make it an answer because I don't see why it should.

Comment: Yes! Thanks @DSM. Perhaps someone familiar with `np.ndarray.astype()` can explain why this works.

Comment: @DSM is right, setting ``dtype=object`` changes the data from a fundamental numpy type to a python object (well it doesn't actually *change* it, but allows it to change). Operations on ``object`` dtypes will be much less performant of course (but see as you want to take the data out prob matters less 2 u)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, it might turn out that you don't need this, but to answer the immediate question, you can use the [`item`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) method.  For example:

```
In [78]: x = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])

In [79]: x.dtype
Out[79]: dtype('float64')

In [80]: x.item(0)
Out[80]: 1.0

In [81]: type(x.item(0))
Out[81]: float

In [82]: y = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int32)

In [83]: type(y.item(0))
Out[83]: int

In [84]: type(y[0])
Out[84]: numpy.int32
```

To convert the entire array at once, the [`tolist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method converts the elements to the nearest compatible Python type:

```
In [95]: xlist = x.tolist()

In [96]: xlist
Out[96]: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]

In [97]: type(xlist[0])
Out[97]: float

In [98]: ylist = y.tolist()

In [99]: ylist
Out[99]: [1, 2, 3]

In [100]: type(ylist[0])
Out[100]: int
```